# MVC3 partial view with ViewModel property as model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to pass a ViewModel property to a partial view, but getting the following error:
"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType2`1[DomaniOnline.Models.DomaniData.TempRates]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DomaniOnline.Models.DomaniData.TempRates'."

How do I pass the VM property so that it is not an anonymous type?

The View:

```
@model DomaniOnline.Models.ViewModels.CompareRatesViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Rate Comparison";
}

<h2>Compare Rates</h2>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.TempRate1.CarrierName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.TempRate2.CarrierName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.TempRate3.CarrierName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.TempRate4.CarrierName)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.Partial("_TempRatesPartial", new { tempRate = Model.TempRate1 })</td>
    <td>@Html.Partial("_TempRatesPartial", new { tempRate = Model.TempRate2 })</td>
    <td>@Html.Partial("_TempRatesPartial", new { tempRate = Model.TempRate3 })</td>
    <td>@Html.Partial("_TempRatesPartial", new { tempRate = Model.TempRate4 })</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The Partial View:

```
@model DomaniOnline.Models.DomaniData.TempRates

<fieldset>
   <legend>TempRates</legend>

   <div class="display-label">Carrier Name</div>
   <div class="display-field">
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CarrierName)
   </div>
....
</fieldset>
```

And the ViewModel:

```
 public class CompareRatesViewModel
 {
    public TempRates TempRate1 { get; set; }
    public TempRates TempRate2 { get; set; }
    public TempRates TempRate3 { get; set; }
    public TempRates TempRate4 { get; set; }
    public TempRates TempRate5 { get; set; }

    public CompareRatesViewModel(IEnumerable<TempRates> TempRateList)
    {
        this.TempRate1 = TempRateList[0];
        this.TempRate2 = TempRateList[1];
        this.TempRate3 = TempRateList[2];
        this.TempRate4 = TempRateList[3];
        this.TempRate5 = TempRateList[4];
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your anonymous type as the type that is the model of your partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("_TempRatesPartial", (DomaniOnline.Models.DomaniData.TempRates)Model.TempRate1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just pass in the object directly rather than using an anonymous type?
Your partial takes TempRates and your TempRate1 is of type TempRate so you should be able to do this without casting.

```
<td>@Html.Partial("_TempRatesPartial", Model.TempRate1)</td>
```